# MSAL.js for API calls from AngularJS with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, msal.js, adal.js

Currently my application is using ADAL.js to get cached Azure AD token from angularJS application and call API methods of ASP.NET Core hosted.

Planning to migrate ADAL.JS to MSAL.js as support is stopped [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration#:%7E:text=A%3A%20Yes.,features%20and%20to%20stay%20secure.)

For AngularJS I am not able find reference documents for migration and also couldnt find any technical blogs for AngularJS. For other technologies its coming.

Help me on how to migrate ADAL.js to MSAL.js for Azure AD Authentication for AngularJS+ASP.NET Core application.

Answer (score 1):

When migrating ADAL.js to MSAL.js, you need to use [`@azure/msal-angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) that is based on [Microsoft identity platform v2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison).

There is an [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api) using MSAL Angular and call a .NET Core web API.

For more details, see:

- [Migration guide to update to MSAL.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-compare-msal-js-and-adal-js)
- [Migrating applications to MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration)

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I couldnt find reference documents for implementing MSAL.js in AngularJS SPA running with ASP.NET Core. My app is not an Angular 2 App.

Comment: Get it. You could try [`@azure/msal-angularjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angularjs) for AngularJS SPA.

Comment: did you find an answer? i'm looking to upgrade too